# ListView Elements with variable width and height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

My `ListView` contains an custom element. Its a view which I extended from the Android View class.
In the method `onMeasure()` I set up the width and the height of the view, which works fine so far including the padding.

Now I tried to use it in the `ListView` and there's something wrong. If the List loads the first time everything looks good so far.
If I scroll down nothing is how it is supposed to be anymore. Height's are wrong width's are wrong and even their padding is wrong.

My guess: It reuses the views and does not call `onMeasure` anymore.

So I thought I call it myself after filling my view with new content (in the adapter method `getView`)

It does not work either.

My View contains maximum 3 elements top:Text, mid:Image(s), bottom:Text
both text's are optional and the number of images minimum is 1. And the height of the images are fix.

So my view looks like the following:

```
This is my Text
|IMAGE1|IMAGE2|
This is my second text
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: i think you are supposed to give heigh and width in getView, not in onMeasure

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I am using the onMeasure Method of my own view to setup the height and width. Isn't that what I need to do? How am I supposed to setup height and width in the getView call?

Comment: use view.getLayoutParams().width and height in the getView

Comment: Well, I still don't get it. How do I have to SET the params? They change from item to item. Do I have to override the Method in my view?

Comment: I just tried overriding the getLayoutParams Method. No changes! :( I still get messed up heights and widths

Comment: Just tried to call in getView-Method of the adapter "view.getLayoutParams().height = newheight" still does not change anything.

Comment: strange, as it is supposed to be how it works